# Ejecutar un trigger solamente tras la actualización de una columna (SQL SERVER)

Tags: sql, sql-server, trigger

Quiero que el trigger que estoy creando ejecute un código solamente en la actualización de cierta columna. Hasta ahora lo que se me ocurre y he encontrado es:

```
CREATE TRIGGER <nombreTrigger>
ON <nombreBD>.dbo.<nombreTabla>
AFTER UPDATE
AS
  IF UPDATE (<nombreColumna>)
  BEGIN
    ...
  END
END
```

Sin embargo, siento como si esto fuese una especie de "parche" y buscaría una solución donde pueda directamente especificar que el trigger se ejecute en la actualización de este campo `<nombreColumna>`

Comment: Todo lo contrario, la forma como lo has hecho es la correcta. Nop puedes asignar un trigger a una columna en concreto. Lo que puedes hacer es asignar un trigger a una tabla como estás haciendo y comprobar si tu columna se ha modificado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alberto, la ejecución de los triggers en SQL Server es a nivel de fila/registro, de hecho en otros motores como Oracle la mecánica es similar. ¿Por qué a nivel de fila y no a nivel de columna? es una buena pregunta, como para hacer una nueva. Imagino que un tema puede ser de rendimiento, mantener TRIGGERs a nivel de columna puede ser más costoso. Lo concreto que la forma en que estás planteando el TRIGGER es la correcta y en realidad la única. Una sola aclaración, que puede resultar obvia para algunos: En SQL Server los triggers se "ejecutan" por el "lote" de `UPDATE\INSERT\DELETE` (Statement level), es decir si actualizamos un conjunto de registros con una única sentencia, el TRIGGER se ejecutará una única vez y no por cada fila (row level), por lo que la lógica del mismo debe estar preparada para considerar múltiples registros.

Answer (score 0):

¿Por qué piensas eso?, "una especie de parche" no lo es, sin duda, de hecho la función UPDATE(column) -función de ámbito de trigger- tiene como tarea comprobar si una operación de inserción o actualización afectó a la columna que pasas como parámetro, es indicada para lo que requieres. 
Sin embargo, la función retorna True **incluso cuando el valor de la columna no ha cambiado**, y eso podría ser contraproducente si no es lo que esperas. Para esos casos lo que yo hago es comprobar si el valor de la columna -en una operación de actualización- es distinto entre las pseudo-tablas inserted y deleted, por ejemplo:

```
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.TriggerName
ON dbo.TableName
AFTER UPDATE
AS
BEGIN 
    UPDATE t
    SET t.AnotherColumn = 'NewValue'
    FROM 
       inserted i 
       INNER JOIN deleted d  ON i.id = d.id AND i.ColumnName <> d.ColumnName 
       INNER JOIN TableName t ON i.id = t.id
END
GO
```